# Unselectable vertex

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects

Hi I have problem with my human-like something model. Basically I created it and scale to human size but there appear some weird line and its unselectable. The real question is why its unselectable and how to delete it.
[image: Object mode]

[image: Edit mode 1]

[image: Edit mode 2]

Here is link for .blend file:  http://www.mediafire.com/file/p1y2amz7o14shzx/IGI.blend/file
Please for quick answer and thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vertex is hidden.

To unhide it, select the mesh and go into edit mode <kbd>Tab</kbd>.
Then press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> to unhide all. The vertex will appear.